# WCF Address Already In Use after adding client endpoint

Tags: wcf, exception, configuration, wcf-binding

I have a WCF Service that is self hosted and started through another service. Debugging in visual studio, they work just fine until I add endpoint configurations to my `app.config` for the service clients. Some clients for this service will be local and others remote. I have tried only having client endpoints for named pipes, if there's a client endpoint pointing to the service, and a client using the endpoint (even though it shouldn't even be instantiated at the point the service tries to start) I get an exception telling me that 0.0.0.0:8524 is in use. Here's the relevant configuration:

```
<service name="EventService.EventPublishingService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" address="net.tcp://localhost:8524/EventPublishingService" contract="EventService.Contracts.IEventPublishService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8524/EventPublishingService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/EventPublishingServicePipe"
           binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="EventService.Contracts.IEventPublishService"
           listenUriMode="Explicit">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
        </host>
     </service>
```

For client endpoints I have tried both

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8524/EventPublishingService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IEventPublishService"
            contract="AGX.Atlas.EventService.Contracts.IEventPublishService" name="NetTcpBinding_IEventPublishService">
         </endpoint>
```

and

```
<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/EventPublishingServicePipe"
        binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEventPublishService"
        contract="AGX.Atlas.EventService.Contracts.IEventPublishService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEventPublishService">
     </endpoint>
```

I've removed the net.pipe binding from the service when removing the client binding as well to make sure it wasn't doing something weird with that. Still the same issue.

Here's the binding configurations:

```
 <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IEventPublishService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
           transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
           hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
           maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
           </security>
        </binding>
     </netNamedPipeBinding>
     <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IEventPublishService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
           transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
           hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
           maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IEventSubscriptionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
           transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
           hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
           maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
           <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
           </security>
        </binding>
     </netTcpBinding>
```